# How to make a function return a promise if optional callback is not passed?

Tags: javascript

I could come up with

```
 function squareAsync(val, callback) {
if (callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            callback(undefined, val * val);
        }
        else {
            callback(new Error('Failed!'));
        }
    }, 2000);
}
else {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                resolve(val * val);
            }
            else {
                reject(new Error('Failed!'));
            }
        }, 2000);
   });
 }
}
```

I found another way for this

```
 function squareAsync1(val, callback) {
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            resolve(val * val);
        }
        else {
            reject(new Error('Failed!'));
        }
    }, 2000);
});
if (callback) {
    p.then(d => {
        callback(undefined, d);
    }, e => {
        callback(e);
    });
 }
return p;
}
```

Which one of these is better or there is a more standard and elegant way of doing this? Can we do this using `async/await`?

Comment: why are you calling callback with undefined as a first parameter ?

Comment: @marcelotokarnia in case of success when there is no error I am passing it as `undefined` as I prefer it instead of `null`.

Comment: besides that, the second approach is a bit better, because on the first one, sometimes the function would return a promise, other times it would return null

Comment: besides that, on the second approach I would also `return callback` inside the `then`, so you can work with promise chains.

Comment: Oooo, I get it, your first parameter is an error and the second is a value :) your callback works for both success and error ... I get it ... makes sense :)

Comment: @marcelotokarnia yeah to illustrate it `resolves/rejects` randomly :)

Comment: The second version avoids duplicating code, so it's more DRY. Other than that, there's nothing to recommend one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```js
function squareAsync(val, callback) {
  const timeout = function(res, rej){
    setTimeout(function(){
      if (Math.random() < 0.5)
        res(val*val);
      else
        rej(new Error('Failed!'));
    }, 2000);
  }
  
  return typeof callback === 'function'
    ? timeout(callback.bind(null, undefined), callback)
    : new Promise(timeout);
}

// CALLBACK EXAMPLE
squareAsync(5, (err, val) => {
  if (err)
    console.log(`Callback: ${err}`);
  else
    console.log(`Callback: ${val}`);
})

// PROMISE EXAMPLE
squareAsync(5)
  .then(val => console.log(`Promise: ${val}`))
  .catch(err => console.log(`Promise: ${err}`))
```

**Explanation**

1. Wrap your `setTimeout` call into one wrapper function `timeout` so that you don't have to repeat your almost identical code.
2. Let `timeout` function take two arguments: `res` and `rej` *(resolve and reject)*
3. Return `timeout` if callback is passed with a function, else return `new Promise(timeout)`.

Now as to what happen in:

```
return typeof callback === 'function'
  ? timeout(callback.bind(null, undefined), callback)
  : new Promise(timeout);
```

It translates to:

```
if (typeof callback === 'function'){
  // Bind `null` as `this` value to `callback
  // and `undefined` as its first argument (because no error).
  // Need to to this because in `timeout` function,
  // we call `res` with only 1 argument (computed value) if success.
  const resolve = callback.bind(null, undefined);

  // Don't need to bind anything
  // because the first argument should be error.
  const reject = callback;

  // Call the function as if we are in a Promise
  return timeout(resolve, reject);
}

// Use `timeout` function as normal promise callback.
return new Promise(timeout);
```

Hope you understand. Feel free to comment if confused.

[More about bind.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: You have to be careful to maintain functions that will return different types depending on the parameters, as I commented on the original question. In your example you can do promise chaining if you not pass a callback but you can't if you do. That's a bit harsh to maintain, specially if your callback is a variable possibly undefined. I suggest you return an auto resolved promised even if you receive a callback.

Answer (score 1):

```
 async function squareAsync1(val, callback) {
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            resolve(val * val);
        }
        else {
            reject(new Error('Failed!'));
        }
    }, 2000);
});
if (callback) {
    return p.then(d => {
        return callback(undefined, d);
    }, e => {
        return callback(e);
    });
 }
return p;
}
```

Yes, your solution will work with async/await. Notice I just added `return` to the p.then

This way you can do something like:

```
const x = await squareAsync1(2, (e, v) => e ? 1 : v * 2)
```

And you will get `x` as either 1 (if the promise was rejected) or 8 (if the promise was successful)